# how to make this into a nest loop

Tags: vb.net

Hello all I got my code and the number are finally right the only thing is i can not get it to loop right. It should ask the user if they would like to buy more bars and if they say yes it should continue if it says no then it should exit but everything i am trying is not working. I am starting to think it is how i am putting the information into the program can someone point out where i am screwing up at thanks.

```
Sub Main()

    ' declare variable

    Dim Answer As Char

    Do
        Console.Write("Would you like to buy some candy bars(1=Yes/0=No)? ")
        Answer = CChar(Console.ReadLine())
    Loop Until Answer = "1"

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of candy you want to buy")
    Console.WriteLine()


    Dim amountDollar As Integer
    Dim leftOverCoupons As Integer
    Dim numberofChocolate As Integer
    Dim freeChocolate As Integer
    amountDollar = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
    numberofChocolate = amountDollar
    leftOverCoupons = numberofChocolate
    While (leftOverCoupons >= 7)
        freeChocolate = CInt(Math.Truncate(leftOverCoupons / 7))
        numberofChocolate = numberofChocolate + freeChocolate
        leftOverCoupons = (leftOverCoupons Mod 7) + freeChocolate

    End While



    Console.WriteLine("Total number of chocolate: " & numberofChocolate)
    Console.WriteLine("Leftover Coupons: " & leftOverCoupons)
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Comment: Well for starters, your candy store holds people hostage until they agree to buy candy bars... ;)  In seriousness though, are you hoping to nest the second loop within the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly what isn't working?  You mention that if the user selects "no" then the application should exit.  However, your loop is continuing until the user selects "yes":

```
Do
    Console.Write("Would you like to buy some candy bars(1=Yes/0=No)? ")
    Answer = CChar(Console.ReadLine())
Loop Until Answer = "1"
```

You don't even really need a loop for this at all.  Just prompt the user once and read their response.  If it's "no" then exit the application.  (Something like `Application.Exit()`.)  If it's "yes" then continue with the rest of the logic.

(Additionally, if the input is something other than "no" or "yes" you can either re-prompt, which may involve a loop, or return an error, or exit the application, etc.  What you want to do with unexpected input is up to you, but should be considered.)

Comment: I understand what you are saying.. they assignment i have been working on for 3 days is saying the best way to solve this is a loop then to use a nested loop to ask if they would like to do it again. Right now it is confusing me so bad it is not funny.

Comment: @sha: Well, take a step back for a moment and ask yourself (for the purposes of grasping the assignment, I suppose) what a loop is doing and what logic needs to be looped in this case.  For example, when you say that an answer of "no" should exit everything, does that mean it really exits the application or that it goes back to the start of the loop (as it does in your code)?  One possible set of nested looping logic for this could be: `while prompting for a sale (if answer is yes (while prompting for a coupon (make sale)))`

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking you're looking for something like this:

```
Sub Main()

' declare variable

Dim Answer As Char

Console.Write("Would you like to buy some candy bars(1=Yes/0=No)? ")
Answer = CChar(Console.ReadLine())

While (Answer = 1)

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of candy you want to buy")
    Console.WriteLine()


    Dim amountDollar As Integer
    Dim leftOverCoupons As Integer
    Dim numberofChocolate As Integer
    Dim freeChocolate As Integer
    amountDollar = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
    numberofChocolate = amountDollar
    leftOverCoupons = numberofChocolate
    While (leftOverCoupons >= 7)
        freeChocolate = CInt(Math.Truncate(leftOverCoupons / 7))
        numberofChocolate = numberofChocolate + freeChocolate
        leftOverCoupons = (leftOverCoupons Mod 7) + freeChocolate

    End While



    Console.WriteLine("Total number of chocolate: " & numberofChocolate)
    Console.WriteLine("Leftover Coupons: " & leftOverCoupons)

    Console.Write("Would you like to buy more candy bars(1=Yes/0=No)? ")
    Answer = CChar(Console.ReadLine())

End While

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a loop at all? A simple if statement to check if the answer is 1 else Application.Exit()

Comment: I am suppose to use a nested loop to ask the user if they would like to buy candy bars again. This has got me so confused it is not funny.